# PHP and Google Analytics core reporting api v3 - get list of profile Ids - not account Ids

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

This questions is more to do with the mechanics of PHP versus the intricacies of Googles Core Reporting API

My goal is to modify the code below(taken from Google's HelloAnalyticsApi.php) so that it will loop through and "printf" a list of **profile ids** from **all** of my respective google analytics accounts.

Currently,the code below goes through and grabs the first profile ID of the first account it sees.  It does so by first obtaining the Account Id, then the web property of that account Id, then finally, the account's profile Id. This is accomplished in the *getFirstprofileId(&$analytics)* function.  As is, the code works fine.

In my case, I have to skip the first one (position 0 in the array) because although it is an account that gets listed, it doesn't have any webproperties.  Therefore, I have to start counting from 1 instead of 0.

(i'll skip the credentials / login and just get the working logic)

```
if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

} else {
    $analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($client);
    runMainDemo($analytics); 

}

function runMainDemo(&$analytics) {
  try {

    // Step 2. Get the user's first profile ID.
    $profileId = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    if (isset($profileId)) {

      // Step 3. Query the Core Reporting API.
      $results = getResults($analytics, $profileId);

      // Step 4. Output the results.
      printResults($results);
    }

  } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    // Error from the API.
    print 'There was an API error : ' . $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'There wan a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {

  $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();


  if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {

    $items = $accounts->getItems();
    $firstAccountId = $items[1]->getId(); 
    //item 0 is an account that gets listed but doesn't have any webproperties.  
    //This account doesn't show in our analytics

    $webproperties = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

    if (count($webproperties->getItems()) > 0) {

      $items = $webproperties->getItems();
      $firstWebpropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

      $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstWebpropertyId);

      if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {

        $items = $profiles->getItems();
        return $items[0]->getId();

      } else {
        throw new Exception('No profiles found for this user.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception('No webproperties found for this user.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}



function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2010-03-03',
      '2011-03-03',
       'ga:visits');
}


function printResults(&$results) {

  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
    $profileId = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileId();

    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $visits = $rows[0][0];

    print "<p>First profile found: $profileName</p>";
    print "<p>First profileId found (not account id): $profileId</p>";
    print "<p>Total visits: $visits</p>";

  } else {
    print '<p>No results found.</p>';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy...Modified function - added for loop.  Looped by number of items in account:

```
function getProfileId(&$analytics) {

    //function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {

      $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

        $num = count($accounts->getItems());


        for ($i=1; $i < $num; $i++) { 

          if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {

            $items = $accounts->getItems();
            $firstAccountId = $items[$i]->getId(); 
            //item 0 is an account that gets listed but doesn't have any webproperties.  
            //This account doesn't show in our analytics

            $webproperties = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

            if (count($webproperties->getItems()) > 0) {

              $items = $webproperties->getItems();
              $firstWebpropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

              $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstWebpropertyId);

              if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {

                $items = $profiles->getItems();

                $profileId = $items[0]->getId();

                print "<p>Profile ID (not account id): ".  $profileId."</p>";



              } else {
                throw new Exception('No profiles found for this user.');
              }
            } else {
              throw new Exception('No webproperties found for this user.');
            }
          } else {
            throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
          }

      }

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the posting, this is a very current question I do have, can you please walk me through the steps, that will be highly appreciated! and did you have to add the developer email to the user profile? thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I realize it has been over a year.  The first part of your question is a bit unclear to me.  What steps are you referring to?  For your second question: Yes, the email that you use to log into your custom app must have read rights to the URL *WITH* a web property within your analytics. So if you have several URLs in your Google Analytics, each URL (account) must have that email associated with it.  If you attempt to use the code above and one of your accounts within your analytics does NOT have web property, the code will crash.